# How can I change slide effects to fade effects? Code is below

Tags: jquery, fade

I have this code with slide effects and I want a effects like for example http://ledlumen.at
Which and where I have to change that can be work?

Thanks in advance!
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

        //Set Default State of each portfolio piece
        $(".paging").show();
        $(".paging a:first").addClass("active");

        //Get size of images, how many there are, then determin the size of the image reel.
        var imageWidth = $(".window").width();
        var imageSum = $(".image_reel img").size();
        var imageReelWidth = imageWidth * imageSum;

        //Adjust the image reel to its new size
        $(".image_reel").css({'width' : imageReelWidth});

        //Paging + Slider Function
        rotate = function(){    
            var triggerID = $active.attr("rel") - 1; //Get number of times to slide
            var image_reelPosition = triggerID * imageWidth; //Determines the distance the image reel needs to slide

            $(".paging a").removeClass('active'); //Remove all active class
            $active.addClass('active'); //Add active class (the $active is declared in the rotateSwitch function)

            $(".desc").stop(true,true).slideUp('slow');

            $(".desc").eq( $('.paging a.active').attr("rel") - 1 ).slideDown("slow"); 

            //Slider Animation
            $(".image_reel").animate({ 
                left: -image_reelPosition
            }, 1200 ); 
        }; 

        //Rotation + Timing Event
        rotateSwitch = function(){  
        $(".desc").eq( $('.paging a.active').attr("rel") - 1 ).slideDown("slow");   
            play = setInterval(function(){ //Set timer - this will repeat itself every 3 seconds
                $active = $('.paging a.active').next();
                if ( $active.length === 0) { //If paging reaches the end...
                    $active = $('.paging a:first'); //go back to first
                }
                rotate(); //Trigger the paging and slider function
            }, 10000); //Timer speed in milliseconds (3 seconds)    

        };

        rotateSwitch(); //Run function on launch

     //On Click
        $(".paging a").click(function() {    
            $active = $(this); //Activate the clicked paging
            //Reset Timer
            clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
            rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
            rotateSwitch(); // Resume rotation
            return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
        });  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `slideDown` with `fadeIn` and `slideUp` with `fadeOut`.

You also have to change this:

```
$(".image_reel").animate({ 
    left: -image_reelPosition
}, 1200 );
```

Change it to something like:

```
$(".image_reel").fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).css('left', -image_reelPosition+'px');
    $(".image_reel").fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: Thanks bro- I did it but it doesn't change. I still have sliding effects.

Comment: Thanks bro. It works but I have 4 pictures there. It start to fade but the picture does not change. It hangs in pic one. No further changes. Any way thanks and hope you will find me the further solution. I am very newby in JS and I wont spoil the codes.

Comment: Thank you again. It is better than before. Photos are changing but at the end there is no image. White. Here you can see what we are trying to. http://www.himalmedia.at/

Comment: Sure but I dont have enough reputation. I am very new here. My Skype id "rupak7eight" may be could work here. But thank you for your consideration. Till in Skype bro!

Comment: I have nothing changed. Skype's not possible, sorry, it's too buggy at the moment on my pc. But you can find a link to my Google+-profile on my homepage linked in my SO-profile.

Comment: Any way I choose nivo slider and it works fantastic. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

[fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) might be your new friends. Try to play around with it when replacing **slideUp** and **slideDown**.

Comment: Thanks bro- I did it but it is still the same here.